# How to use Sonarqube as a service locally on mac?

Tags: ios, macos, sonarqube

How to install SonarQube as a service locally on my mac (os sierra 10.12.5)?

Comment: Do you need SonarQube to be automatically started every time macOs boots?

Comment: I need to use sonar qube to analyze my swift code when ever i ask it to analyze and show the results of my code.

Answer (score 8):

[Download SonarQube](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/sonarqube/downloads/success-download-community-edition/), unzip it and execute `bin/macosx-universal-64/sonar.sh console` in a terminal. Now open a browser, got to `http://localhost:9000` and follow the instructions.

Comment: The "Get Started" link above is no longer valid, looks like you can go here now to download a free version of SonarQube. https://www.sonarsource.com/products/sonarqube/downloads/success-download-community-edition/